# How to get ClientID of asp.net control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to get full ClientID, that generated by ASP.NET. I try to do it like this:

```
protected override void OnPreREnder(EventArgs e)
{
    var fullID = myCoolControlID.ClientID;
}
```

I use fullID for JS that connected with help of

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript();
```

But after page load I see that fullID return only "myCoolControlID", but I need in ID like this: "ct100_parentID_clientID..._myCoolControlID".

Answer (score 0):

Use `BehaviorID` instead of `ClientID`